# manipulating TSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a .tsv file of text data, linked here: 
[world bank data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uaxptvphcg0ue4o/world_bank_indicators.txt)

I need to read the data into a data structure (any data structure), keep only rows with the date "7/1/2000" or 7/1/2010", and keep only 7 of the original 19 columns.  I'm pretty new to programming, but I thought this would be a fairly straightforward task.  I have code here that is incomplete:

```
import math
import csv
import re


fhand=open("world_bank_indicators.txt", "rU")
reader=csv.reader(fhand, dialect="excel", delimiter="\t",skipinitialspace=True)

data=dict()
mylist=list()

#doesn't print headers, however
for row in reader:
    if row[1]=="7/1/2000" or row[1]=="7/1/2010":
        print row[0], row[1], row[9], row[4], row[6], row[5], row[19]
```

UPDATE, version using dictreader:

```
import math
import csv
import re

fhand=open("world_bank_indicators.txt", "rU")
reader=csv.reader(fhand, dialect="excel", delimiter="\t", lineterminator="\n")

reader=csv.DictReader(fhand, delimiter="\t")
myset=set()
mydict=dict()
mylist=list()

for row in reader:
    mydict["Date"]=row["Date"]

print mydict
```

however, this only seems to write one entry {date:7/1/2010} to my dict

so, my obvious issues are:

1) this does print the rows and columns of data I want, however, it doesn't print the headers of each column
2) obviously, nothing has been added to any data structure yet in order for me to perform any calculations with the data

what (painfully obvious, I'm sure) thing am I missing here?  How can I accomplish these two simple tasks?

Comment: Posting a sample datafile (or a link to a sample datafile) would be helpful.

Comment: use a csv.DictReader which will give you the rows back as dictionaries with the header as the keys.

Comment: I tried using dictreader, but I kept getting issues when it came to writing certain key: value pairs to a list or dict of my choosing.

Comment: The reason your second version "seems to write one entry" is that you write all of the entries to the same place, `mydict["Date"]`. Each time you assign a new value to that, it replaces the old one. So, at the end, you just have the very last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to print the headers, all you have to do is print the first row's columns out, the same way you do for all the `7/1/2000` row's columns. For example:

```
headers = next(reader)
print row[0], row[1], row[9], row[4], row[6], row[5], row[19]

for row in reader:
    if row[1]=="7/1/2000" or row[1]=="7/1/2010":
        print row[0], row[1], row[9], row[4], row[6], row[5], row[19]
```

This isn't actually generating a TSV, however; you're just separating the columns by a single space. Plus, of course, you're just `print`ing them to stdout, not writing them to a file. The easiest solution is to use a `csv.writer` the same way you used the `csv.reader`:

```
writer=csv.writer(outfile, dialect="excel", delimiter="\t",skipinitialspace=True)
# …
writer.writerow(row[0], row[1], row[9], row[4], row[6], row[5], row[19])
```

To make this a little cleaner, and avoid repeating that column list twice, you may want to use `operator.itemgetter`, like this:

```
columns = 0, 1, 9, 4, 6, 5, 19
getter = operator.itemgetter(*columns)
# ...
writer.writerow(getter(row))
```

If you want to store the values rather than write them out, just pass them to the `append` method of a `list` object, instead of the `writerow` method of a `csv.writer` object. (You probably also want to keep `headers` around as well.)

```
headers = getter(next(reader))

data = []
for row in reader:
    if row[1]=="7/1/2000" or row[1]=="7/1/2010":
        data.append(getter(row))
```

You can make this more concise with a comprehension:

```
data = [getter(row) for row in reader if row[1]=="7/1/2000" or row[1]=="7/1/2010"]
```

---

If you want to use a `DictReader` instead, you won't get the columns by index anymore, you'll get them by *name*. Also, a `DictReader` automatically consumes the header row, to figure out those names. Here's a simplified example. Imagine this was your data:

```
name,email,rank
Joe,joe@example.com,7
Jim,jim@example.com,12
Jen,jane@example.com,2
```

And let's say we just wanted the email of people in the top 10. So, here it is with `reader`:

```
reader = csv.reader(f)
headers = next(reader)
data = [row[1] for row in reader if int(row[2]) < 10]
```

And here it is with `DictReader`:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(f)
data = [row['email'] for row in reader if int(row['rank']) < 10]
```

It may not be quite as concise, but it's probably more readable.